# TypeScript compiler: generated sources, root dirs, excludes and symlinks

Tags: typescript, compilation, symlink, tsc

I have this setup of a TypeScript 2.0.3 project:

```
src/main/webapp/tsconfig.json
src/main/webapp/app -- contains .ts files
src/main/webapp/app/tsModels -- a symlink to ../../../../target/tsModels
target/tsModels/   -- contains .ts files
```

The goal is to get the .ts files in `target/tsModels` compiled.

First, with `"rootDir": "."`, `tsc` complained:

> error TS6059: File '[...]/target/tsModels/AboutWindupModel.ts' is not under 'rootDir' '[...]/src/main/webapp'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.

So I tried

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {  ...,
    //"rootDir": ".",
    "rootDirs": [".", "../../../target/tsModels"],
  },
}
```

Still the same. Tried:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    //"rootDir": ".",
    "rootDirs": [".", "../../../target/tsModels"],
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "target/**",
    "../../../target/**", 
    "../../../target/**/*",
    "../../../target/tsModels/*", 
    "typings/main",
    "typings/main.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

But still getting that error.

So it seems that `tsc` can't handle symlinks properly, always checks the canonical path.

So I thought, ok let's compile the `tsModels` files directly. So I removed the symlink and tried:

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    //"rootDir": ".",
    "rootDirs": [".", "../../../target/tsModels"],
  },
```

But this doesn't actually compile the files in the `tsModels` dir.
I have even tried

```
    "rootDirs": "../../../target/tsModels",
```

but `tsc` didn't compile that, instead, it compiled the `.`. Does it obey that at all?

What should I do to compile files from both dirs?
Is there a way to use a symlink leading to dir outside `rootDir`?

Full config with all the garbage I was trying:

`{
      "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "system",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "removeComments": false,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        //"rootDir": ".",
        //"rootDirs": [".", "../../../target/tsModels"],
        "rootDirs": ["../../../target/tsModels"],
        //"rootDir": "../../../target/tsModels", 
        "outDir": "../../../target/windup-web",
        "sourceRoot": "/windup-web/"
      },
      "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        //"target/**",
        //"../../../target/**", 
        //"../../../target/**/*",
        //"../../../target/tsModels/*", 
        //"target/tsModels/**",
        "typings/main",
        "typings/main.d.ts"
      ]
    }`

Answer (score 4):

I think the `preserveSymlinks` compiler option could help you:

> Do not resolve symlinks to their real path; treat a symlinked file like a real one.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html

Example:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "preserveSymlinks": true
    }
}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21446685)

Comment: This is not a link-only answer. The important information - "use preserveSymlinks compiler option" - is in the answer text. The link by itself doesn't answer the question, it's a list of all compiler options and i added it just for reference.

Comment: And in case you feel there wasn't enough information, i added an example.

Comment: Actually I can fail with my review, this is natural. In SO several reviewers should agree before make a decision. And reviewer who fail recieves penalties. Just in my opinion SO is system to create content where "answer" is a unit of content (not thread as on other forums). Asnwer should be an intersting "story" :) do not worry to much if I have failed - other reviewers/moderators review me :) that how it work.